# how to customize JMeter dashboard generation

Tags: jmeter, customization, dashboard

I'm using JMeter 5.1.1. I would like to customize dashboard generation the following way:

I would like to keep generating dashboard with requests and subresults ( jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults) and at the same time I need similar report/table where only:
 the list of active thread groups is mentioned with percentiles, median, error rate values = for business reporting purposes.

Has anyone did customization like this ?
Is it possible to add custom table like this ?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question. If you need to see the KPI (percentiles, median, and error rate etc) vs elapsed time, then pick any listener that shows KPI vs the elapsed time it displays the same for the "active threads" of the current time frame. You can choose the granularity like 500 ms or 5 seconds, it's up to you. And JMeter also groups these KPIs for each request or transaction, it depends on how you choose to display the results.

Comment: yes, I do know you can see/get those values in a listener, but I would like to have a customized html report. My test plan is quite massive, and overview of only active thread groups would be helpful. Also granularity is not the issue here, I would like to compare individual report between runs to each other. With a small test it is easy, but not so on a large scale.

Comment: Have you tried influxDB and Grafana?

Comment: I have considered grafana , but before I try using another tool I was hoping to explore possibilities of freemarker and modify already existing template. That is where I'm aiming with my customization question.